# Unexpected extra result when I don't simplify before solving

Tags: equation-solving, numerics

Why am I seeing two different results below?

```
Solve[2 t^2 - 4.6 t + 1.2 - (1 - 4 t) (0.3 t - 1) == 3.2 t^2]
```

> ```
> {{t -> -4.0082*10^16}, {t -> 0.247191}}
> ```

```
Solve[FullSimplify[2 t^2 - 4.6 t + 1.2 - (1 - 4 t) (0.3 t - 1)] == 3.2 t^2]
```

> ```
> {t -> 0.247191}}
> ```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Up to machine precision, the "wrong" solution is indeed correct:

```
a = 2 t^2 - 4.6 t + 1.2 - (1 - 4 t) (0.3 t - 1) /. 
   t -> -4.008203668359741`*^16;
b = 3.2 t^2 /. t -> -4.008203668359741`*^16;
a == b
(a - b)/a < $MachineEpsilon
```

> True
>
> True

Taking the differences of both sides of the equation also shows us, why this happens:

```
2 t^2 - 4.6 t + 1.2 - (1 - 4 t) (0.3 t - 1) - 3.2 t^2 // Expand
```

> 2.2 - 8.9 t - 2.22045*10^-16 t^2

So, this is really on the edge between quadratic and linear equations.

This tells us that we have to be cautious when solving in machine precision. Often, applying `Rationalize` to the equations before solving does also help.